# ios7: is it possible to email ALL the crash logs from a device?

Tags: ios, ios7, crash-reports, diagnostics, crash-log

OS: iOS-7

I'd like to automatically retrieve all the logs under "`General->About->Diagnostics & Usage->Diagnostics & Usage Data`" for administration purposes.

I know that you can use frameworks like PLCrashReporter or tools like crashlytics or testflight when you want to get crash logs automatically for your app. But this only works for apps that YOU develop, not for all the logs that are stored in the "`Diagnostics & Usage Data`".

I've found an App that might do what I want "`iSyslog`" [(see it in the app store)](https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/isyslog-system-monitoring/id468155763?mt=8), but it says in the description "`Logs cannot be retrieved under iOS7`". Any of you knows if this is true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You really are better off just connecting to a server with http request / JSon etc because you shouldn't send email without involving the user...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

sorry for not being that specific (didn't want to write too much on the initial question). 
This is for a company, who is the owner of the devices, the users are employees. So, it would not be any problem in sending these emails without involving the user.